# How to copy Textbox value from windows application inside footer in OnEndPage

Tags: c#, textbox, itext, footer

I tried several times in google and StackExchange to solve this mystery, i want one of the textbox values in my windows application to be in footer in the PDF file that executed, but the problem i donot know how.
here's a part of my code

```
    public partial class Footer : PdfPageEventHelper
    {

        public override void OnEndPage(PdfWriter wri, Document document)
        {

            Paragraph footer = new Paragraph("footer test"); <=== Here my problem
            footer.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;
            PdfPTable footerTbl = new PdfPTable(1);
            footerTbl.TotalWidth = 300;
            footerTbl.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;
            PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(footer);
            cell.Border = 0;
            cell.PaddingLeft = 10;
            footerTbl.AddCell(cell);
            footerTbl.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, 415, 30, wri.DirectContent);

        }
    }
```

If i execute the PDF file the Footer had only footer test, what i want to know how i can print the Textbox value in the PDF footer .

Regards

Comment: Well firstly you have textox as opposed to textbox

Comment: so i donot understand which two ? i have only one textbox (textbox14.text)

Comment: To quote your code `Paragraph footer = new Paragraph("textox14.text");`

Comment: i modified it, i just need the value inside the Textbox14 to be print in footer

Comment: The question is unclear. You are using a `PdfPageEvent` which means that you are creating a PDF document from scratch. If this PDF has a text field, named `textbox14`, you are also creating this field. If you are creating this field, you know the value of the text added to that text box. So... why would you need to fetch that value from the PDF? That doesn't make sense. Another interpretation of your question, is that `textbox14` is not a field in the PDF file, but some widget in an application. However, as your not telling us anything about that application, no one can help you.

Comment: Ok i will explain more.
i had a windows application have Textbox14.Text , this textbox had a value from my database, when i execute PDF, it must have footer but i cannot put my textbox14 value inside the footer
i will modify my code and question to be more clear

Comment: Paragraph footer = new Paragraph(textBox14.Text);

Comment: i got this error
Error 1 The name 'textox14' does not exist in the current context